# Using VBA to clean data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet of raw data that looks like this with 12169 records.

[image]

I want to use VBA to sort through all of these records and out them into to a clean spreadsheet where regression can be run. My code is below

```
Sub cleandata()
   Dim sVariable As String
   Dim vEntry As Variant
   Dim jCounter As Long
   Dim iCounter As Long
   Dim iEndRow As Long
   Dim sRecord As String
   Dim iRowClean As Long
 
   iRowClean = 0
   For jCounter = 0 To 72865
   
   
sRecord = Sheets("customer_service_Anheuser-Busch").Range("A1").Offset(jCounter, 0)

  If Left(sRecord, 6) <> "Record" Then
     
      iEndRow = Sheets("customer_service_Anheuser-Busch").Range("A1").Offset(jCounter, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
      For iCounter = 1 To iEndRow - 1 Step 2
         
         sVariable = Sheets("customer_service_Anheuser-Busch").Range("A1").Offset(jCounter, iCounter)
         vEntry = Sheets("customer_service_Anheuser-Busch").Range("A1").Offset(jCounter, iCounter + 1)
'1
If sVariable = "Rainfall (Inches)" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("B1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'2
ElseIf sVariable = "Avg. Education (Yrs.)" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("C1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'3
ElseIf sVariable = "Month" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("D1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'4
ElseIf sVariable = "Avg. Household Size" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("E1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'5
ElseIf sVariable = "Population (000s)" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("F1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'6
ElseIf sVariable = "County" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("G1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'7
ElseIf sVariable = "Unemployment Rate" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("H1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'8
ElseIf sVariable = "Num. Microbreweries" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("I1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'9
ElseIf sVariable = "Avg. Income (000s)" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("J1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'10
ElseIf sVariable = "% Home Owners" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("K1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'11
ElseIf sVariable = "% White" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("L1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'12
ElseIf sVariable = "Avg. Commute (mins)" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("M1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'13
ElseIf sVariable = "% Female" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("N1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'14
ElseIf sVariable = "% Democrats" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("O1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'15
ElseIf sVariable = "Log of Help Desk Employees*" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("P1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'16
ElseIf sVariable = "Avg. Employee Wage (000s)" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("Q1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'17
ElseIf sVariable = "Year" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("R1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'18
ElseIf sVariable = "Log of Complaints (per day)*" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("S1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'19
ElseIf sVariable = "Avg. Worker Hours (per day)*" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("T1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'20
ElseIf sVariable = "Num. Starbucks" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("U1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
'21
ElseIf sVariable = "Avg. Age" Then
   Sheets("Clean_Data").Range("V1").Offset(iRowClean, 0) = vEntry
End If
         Next iCounter
Else
         iRowClean = iRowClean + 2
End If

Next jCounter

End Sub
```

When I try to run this, I am getting an error on the line

```
vEntry = Sheets("customer_service_Anheuser-Busch").Range("A1").Offset(jCounter, iCounter + 1)
```

And am not sure what to do about it. The final result I am trying to obtain is a table on a new sheet where the columns are the variables of each record and the rows are every record.

Below is a link with 5 records
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=16PxGZAsRMAWYbcd7WDGyojtTh4BAiNQT

Comment: To help prevent this question getting closed like the last one - maybe just clarify what the final product should look like?  Also - if possible can you share a file with 5-10 records of data?

Comment: Yes, I have just edited my question. Sorry if I wasn't detailed enough

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can do it.  Assumes each record has a 0-1 value for each unique attribute.

```vb
Sub Reformat()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, dictRows As Object, dictCols As Object
    Dim results(), k, data, r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, rec, v
    
    'dictionaries for mapping row and column positions in output array
    Set dictCols = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dictCols.comparemode = 1 'vbTextCompare; case-insensitive
    Set dictRows = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dictCols.comparemode = 1
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'pick up all of the raw data as an array
    data = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(LastOccupiedRow(ws), LastOccupiedColumn(ws))).Value
    
    'Collect all of the unique values (record/attribute names) and map then to
    '  row and column positions
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        rec = data(r, 1)
        If Len(rec) > 0 Then
            'If a new record name then add to dictionary with row index
            If Not dictRows.exists(rec) Then dictRows.Add rec, dictRows.Count + 1
        End If
        
        For c = 2 To UBound(data, 2) Step 2 'data is in name/value pairs
            v = data(r, c)
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                'if a new attribute then add to dictionary with column index
                If Not dictCols.exists(v) Then dictCols.Add v, dictCols.Count + 1
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    'resize the output array and populate row/column headers
    ReDim results(1 To dictRows.Count + 1, 1 To dictCols.Count + 1)
    results(1, 1) = "Record"
    i = 2
    For Each k In dictCols
        results(1, i) = k
        i = i + 1
    Next k
    i = 2
    For Each k In dictRows
        results(i, 1) = k
        i = i + 1
    Next k
    
    'now fill the results array
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        If Len(data(r, 1)) > 0 Then rec = data(r, 1)
        If Len(rec) > 0 Then
            For c = 2 To UBound(data, 2) Step 2
                v = data(r, c)
                If Len(v) > 0 Then
                    results(dictRows(rec) + 1, dictCols(v) + 1) = data(r, c + 1) 'store attribute value
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next r
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").Resize(dictRows.Count + 1, dictCols.Count + 1).Value = results
    End With
    
End Sub

'Find last-occupied row/column
Function LastOccupiedRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedRow = f.Row
End Function
Function LastOccupiedColumn(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then LastOccupiedColumn = f.Column
End Function
```

Tested on your sample data and looks OK...

Comment: If this works on your full dataset I'd be interested in how long it takes to run...